# React Router v6 useRouteMatch equivalent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

When using React Router v5, it was possible to get the path (pattern) for that route using [`useRouteMatch`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useroutematch).

```js
const { path } = useRouteMatch();
```

React Router v6 offers a similar hook, [`useMatch`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-match); however this expects to receive the pattern you want to match against.

I would use the React Router v5 hook to generate routes by combining the current path with known params.

As an example, if I am on the product page of an eCommerce application (let's assume `/en/product/:id`) and there are links to related products (`/en/product/1`, `/en/product/2`...etc), I would previously have been able to do:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const { path } = useRouteMatch();
  return (
    <div>
      <Link to={generatePath(path, { id: 1 })}>Related Product 1</Link>
      <Link to={generatePath(path, { id: 2 })}>Related Product 2</Link>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Since `/en/product` comes from an API and is not declared anywhere in the code, I would want the URLs to be updated based on the current path. If the user is on `/es/producto`, then the links would automatically be updated to `/es/producto/1`.

I have seen solutions on SO where it was suggested to use `matchRoutes`, however it feels highly inefficient, especially since the routes are dynamically generated from an external API.

```
const useCurrentPath = () => {
  const location = useLocation()
  const [{ route }] = matchRoutes(routes, location)

  return route.path
}
```

I have created a small demo to illustrate how this used to work:

[Code Sandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-use-route-match-v5-93jpzg?file=/src/App.jsx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `react-router-dom@6` there is no replacement for the v5 `useRouteMatch` hook. The links and routes no longer need to be concerned with the `path` pattern so much as they can simply use relative routes and links. Instead of trying to access a route's path pattern it can simply navigate relative to the currently matched path.

Example:

This navigates from `"/route-a/2"` to `"/route-a/2/../1"` or rather `"/route-a/1"`.

```
const { pathname } = useLocation();

// navigate to sibling route path
<Link to={`${pathname}/../${RELATED_ID}`}>
  Go to Nested Route {RELATED_ID}
</Link>
```

### Demo

[image: Edit react-router-v6-useroutematch-equivalent]

Fullcode:

```
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Link,
  Route,
  Routes,
  useParams,
  useLocation
} from "react-router-dom";
import "./styles.css";

const RELATED_ID = 1;

const MyComponent = ({ title }) => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  const { id } = useParams();
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>
        {title} {id}
      </h1>
      <pre>{pathname}</pre>
      {id && RELATED_ID && (
        <Link to={`${pathname}/../${RELATED_ID}`}>
          Go to Nested Route {RELATED_ID}
        </Link>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <nav>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          <Link to="/route-a">Route A</Link>
          <Link to="/route-b">Route B</Link>
          <Link to="/route-a/1">Nested Route A1</Link>
          <Link to="/route-a/2">Nested Route A2</Link>
          <Link to="/route-b/1">Nested Route B1</Link>
          <Link to="/route-b/2">Nested Route B2</Link>
        </nav>
        <Routes>
          <Route
            path="/route-b"
            element={<MyComponent title="Nested Route" />}
          />
          <Route
            path="/route-a"
            element={<MyComponent title="Nested Route" />}
          />
          <Route
            path="/route-b/:id"
            element={<MyComponent title="Nested Route" />}
          />
          <Route
            path="/route-a/:id"
            element={<MyComponent title="Nested Route" />}
          />
          <Route path="/" />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 22):

In react-router-dom v5

```
// Receive the matched url of the current <Route/>
const { url } = useRouteMatch();
```

In react-router-dom v6

```
const url = useResolvedPath("").pathname;
```

Comment: It really, really bugs me how often the React Router API changes from one version to the next.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the black magic. It's annoying, a nightmare, to upgrade react router to v6

Answer (score -1):

`useMatch` seems to be the actual replacement for `useRouteMatch`: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5#replace-useroutematch-with-usematch

Comment: OP already mentions `useMatch` and that it doesn't expose the pattern. Although the docs refer to it as a replacement, it is not in this case. In fact, there is no officially supported replacement to get the pattern.